# Visual Studio 10 not rebuilding

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, build

I made a small change to one of the webpages in a website. Before publishing to the server, I compiled it locally but it appears that no changes have been made. For example, in one of the table cells I would change "Engineers" to "Apples" and when I rebuild and run, it would still say "Engineers". What is strange is that when other people made a copy of the code and ran it, it works perfectly fine.

I tried clearing the current build, resetting all settings, and even reinstalling vs10 completely, but the problem persists.

At this point I have exhausted all attempts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try refreshing your web browser? Try pressing Ctrl-F5 in your browser

Comment: If you're using Firefox, try ctrl-shift-R

Comment: Does your solution have multiple projects?

Comment: try cleaning the project and then create a new build.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently, not necessarily the same but... who knows.

Check in the menu Build -> Configuration Manager. In the right column, make sure all required projects are being built. For some reason, in my case, all of them had been unchecked and when I hit the compile button, nothing would happen because of that.

Answer (score 0):

If Clean + Build, or Rebuild, or manually deleting output files and rebuild doesn't work perhaps it's a caching issue.

Try opening the page in Chrome, open the developer tools `CTRL+SHIFT+I` and then long press on the reload page button and from the dropdown select `Empty Cache and Hard Refresh`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try refreshing your web browser? Try pressing Ctrl-F5 in your browser – Blachshma

This worked! Can't believe it was something so simple. Been looking in the wrong direction the entire time. Thank you so much!

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with chrome. Try clearing your history and then rebuild your application and try once again and that is not problem with VS 2010.Before clearing your history in chrome try to work with another browser and check if it is the same :)